# Resources for Developing on Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

My developers are trying to build on top of Apache. They are posting questions in apache camel forums but not getting much help. Is there a better resource for Apache camel?

Answer (score 2):

You can try out this links,

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/apache-camel-integration

Also to start with, you may consider reading very first chapter of Camel in Action
http://www.manning.com/ibsen/

Also there is complete guide on camel site itself, available with lot's of documentation.
http://camel.apache.org/getting-started.html

And Finally you can start do hands-on with this link
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/getting-started-with-apache-camel.html

Comment: If possible, pls share exactly where your team is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of material on learning and getting started with Apache Camel. Have you team read and learn.

There is many 3rd party blogs / articles / videos / presentations and whatnot listed at: http://camel.apache.org/articles

And there is some steps to follow at the getting started section: http://camel.apache.org/getting-started.html

Especially this article explains really well about Camel: http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-source-integration-apache

And then if you want your team to get better up to speed, then spend some $$$ on buying some of the Camel books: http://camel.apache.org/books.html

The work that goes into a book is much much higher standard than what you find on the free internet.

And if you need faster help and whatnot, then there is commercial support / training etc: http://camel.apache.org/commercial-camel-offerings.html